# How would I convey the information that multiple options can be selected, and just one can be selected as well?

Tags: web

So, this is what my scene looks like: [image]

How would I show the users that they can book only one service, or more than one? I wouldn't want to make a clickable '+' instead of a book button that adds it to a list and at the end you have only one book button, because most of the times users would just book one service.

I thought of having a '+' like the last paragraph says but it only takes 1/3 of the 'book panel' (the black background behind the book text) when someone clicks it then the book services comes up, showing the users they can select various services.

Is the way I thought of alright? Or maybe the idea I'm trying not to recreate is not so critical for the user experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stacy H and Garik have already mentioned, reproducing a toggle-ish button is what you can do in this sense, in case you need visualization this is how it potentially could look like with the different states [image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Looks great! One thing; my only concern was that users would most of the time just book one service, but I wanted to also give them the options of booking multiple services simultaneously, do you think that this extra step to make a singular choice is worth it or is just polluting the user experience?

Comment: You could do both, you see the "Added" state, you can put on the side of it the -+ pattern, meaning once the user clicks on the first add, he/she can then add more

Comment: forgot to say you're welcome :) and theoretically yes you could make a sacrifice, you're the manager it sort of depends on how you decide on things, generally would not recommend it though; it could be perceived colliding with ethics if you deliberately choose to undermine "minorities", in your case you know better ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more obvious that more than one selection is allowed by changing "Book" to "Select" and then putting the selected tiles in a "selected" state -- maybe the black button becomes a vivid color, the tile has a halo, and a checkmark appears next to the word "Select". You can then add a "Check out" or "Book Services" button in a prominent place when the user is finished with their selection.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Makes sense. One thing; my only concern was that users would most of the time just book one service, but I wanted to also give them the options of booking multiple services simultaneously, do you think that this extra step to make a singular choice is worth it or is it just polluting the user experience?

Comment: It might make sense to map out the interaction flow and see how tedious of a process it is to book just one thing. Was it easy or hard to find the one thing? Does the next step take the user through a lot of screens? We're used to ordering from menus and then paying or checking out, so I think as long as the whole process isn't too long or clunky, it can work. It would be good to test your solution on paper prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Use check-boxes. They convey exactly that.

Comment: Or he could make these images function as checkboxes.

Comment: My only concern was that users would most of the time just book one service, but I wanted to also give them the options of booking multiple services simultaneously, do you think that this extra step to make a singular choice is worth it or is just polluting the user experience?

Comment: Levon jan, you are on a right track. It is always a good idea to give the user choices. In this case I see no pollution, just extra flexibility. 

One thing tough the mock-up by UX Labs is good, but use square checkboxes, round ones look like radio buttons (unless checked).

Answer (score 1):

Both button that says "Select this" or existing button with checkbox left should work. 
 You should include system status message on top, like "2/5 selected" and next to it option to "Proceed on checkout".